# MySQL query from three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I built working MySQL query:

```
  SELECT 
    v.*, u.username 
  FROM 
    video AS v, users AS u
  WHERE
    v.type = 'public' 
  AND 
    v.user_ID = u.user_ID
```

Now I want to add a third table and `count()` results from the table `comments` where `video_ID` from this table will be equal to those from the table `video`.

I tried this but it wasn't successful:

```
  SELECT 
    v.*, u.username, count(c.video_ID)
  FROM 
    video AS v, users AS u, comments AS c
  WHERE
    v.type = 'public' 
  AND 
    v.user_ID = u.user_ID
  AND
    v.video_ID = c.video_ID
```

In return I want to get the number of comments related to certain `video_ID`'s.

I don't understand how to make it work correctly in one query.

Could you please help me out?

Thank you in advance,
Ilia

Comment: "but it wasn't successful": what specifically was the error?

Comment: It returned a broken array, everything was kind of mixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using an aggregate function like a `COUNT` in a query, you need to specify the grouping with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this

```
SELECT  
    v.*, 
    u.username, 
    count(c.video_ID) AS comment_count
FROM  
video AS v
     INNER JOIN users AS u ON     v.user_ID = u.user_ID 
     INNER JOIN comments AS c ON    v.video_ID = c.video_ID
WHERE 
 v.type = 'public'  
GROUP BY
    v.id, 
    u.username,
    v.v.add_time
ORDER BY
    v.add_time
```

While MySQL lets you leave out the some elements of the `GROUP BY` clause, it is good practice to specify them.

When joining two tables, it is good practice to use the `INNER JOIN` syntax, rather than a `WHERE` filter.

Comment: It looks so beautiful, thank you but so far I couldn't make it work. My query has to have `*` from video and it's also has a continuation like `ORDER BY v.add_time DESC` but it think it's not the case. The error is `Call to a member function getrows() on a non-object in`, looks like there is a typo, going to double check.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev My fault - I'd missed out an `ON` - see above edit. To add more items from the video table, add them to the `select` *and* group by sections.

Comment: OK! It did the work with counting videos but if you change `v.id` to `v.*` it also queries the rest of the table - this is what I wanted! :) it returned the `key` as `[count(c.VID)]` is this possible to make it, e.g. `comment_count`? Should I just state `count(c.VID) as comment_count`?

Comment: Yes, it works! `count(c.VID) as comment_count`! Thank you so much for teaching, podiluska!! I appreciate! It feels that query happens just a bit slower though!

Comment: I also found out the your code returns only the rows from table `video` which has comments. How do I return all of the videos and set 0 on `comment_count` to those that have 0 comment count? Can I use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Yes, exactly. A LEFT JOIN is just what you want.

Comment: Can I use count() to add two more tables, is this just the same way? For some reason if I use the same logic then the values on the following count() with left join are incorrect? If I can use it in general, I'll just try to research and fix, if not then will look for the other solution?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev that depends which table you choose, and what you want to return!

Comment: This is correct, I just figured this out! Thanks again! All the best to you!